# Repeating of rows on Scroll in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am having a gridView and the data in the gridView is coming from server.
Now I am having some views in it that will show for some rows and will not show for some rows depends on the sever conditions.

Ex : I am having a LinearLayout which is having an imageView and 2 TextViews, this layout will be visible only for some rows based on server data.

First time it is coming fine but as I scroll down/up, the view of the rows get change.

For Ex: Like in the first row If I am not having this LinearLayout and in 2nd or 3rd row this layout is visible, the when I scroll down and then again scroll up, the first row also get that Layout exact same as the last scrolled position.

I am using Holder pattern, can you please help me here, I am stuck here.

Thank you so  much in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The views are stateless so if you show the linearlayout on someviews you need to remember to hide it for the others.

onBindViewHolder will not give you a fresh view from xml but the view you mutated. Basically just remember to set the LinearLayout back to gone.

A better way would be to use multiple xml files and implement getItemViewType showing and hiding views can cause the scroll to gitter, although if heights remain the same you might get away with it.

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    List<ContactsContract.Data> data;

    private static final int TYPE_A = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_B = 1;

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(viewType == TYPE_A) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xml_a, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xml_b, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(data.get(position).youCondition()) {
            return TYPE_A;
        } else {
            return TYPE_B;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

This is a basic example of how it could be done. Will need to implement your own ViewHolders i'd suggest making a different one for each view type from a base class that has the set data method.

Comment: Yes, I am checking conditions, if condition satisfied then only that layout get  visible else I set that layout visibility to gone, but still it is repeating the views.

Actually I am having alot of conditions and using different layout files for each of them will increase the App size which I don't want to be more.

Can you please provide me any solution here. 

Than you so much.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Added a code example. I would really not worry about the size of an extra xml file it will add basically nothing to the end app size. Its just images you should worry about.